# getting error as 'postDetails' not defined no-undef which my state variable

Tags: reactjs

my state variable contains a variable named postDetails (array of objects)  which contains (username, user_Dp, caption, imageUrl).
my state :

```
this.state = {
      postDetails: []
    };
```

the above postDetails state variable is being updated using componentWillMount()

```
componentWillMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3001')
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((data)=>{
      this.setState({postDetails:data});
    });
  }
```

from the different component, I am taking inputs of postDetails and updating the postDetails variable using loadPost()

```
loadPost = (post) =>{
    this.setState({ postDetails: [ ...postDetails, post] });
  }
```

here I am getting an error of postDetails undefined,

> ./src/App.js   Line 40:39:  'postDetails' is not defined  no-undef

can anyone plz help me in solving this problem, it will be very helpful for me to proceed further in my project.

Answer (score 0):

In `loadPost` as far as I understand you are trying to update `postDetails` with the previous state and the new `post` that you are getting from other component. But the `postDetails` state is not being accessed properly. Below is the way you can update

```
loadPost = (post) => {
    this.setState((state) => ({ postDetails: [ ...state.postDetails, post] });
  }
```